# I'm using the WordPress function get_recent_posts. However I wish to include the post thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have browsed on here and found some examples but they don't seem to bring the image in. Here's what I've found so far. This at least shows the links to the posts, but I want need only two posts showing and I need the featured image showing.

```
<!-<div class="recent_posts_home_container">
        <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts();
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div> 
<!-- end recent posts div -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="recent_posts_home_container">
        <h2>Recent Posts</h2>
            <ul>
                <?php
                    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
                    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
                    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
                        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
                        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'thumbnail');
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

**TIP** :Before putting question here try looking over [**Wordpress Stackexchange**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and [**codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function the_gallery() {

    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment',          'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) 
    {
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id);
    }
}
```

I also share you some reference links that will really help you get more understanding of this issue:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-all-the-attached-images-of-the-posts

http://wpengineer.com/1735/easier-better-solutions-to-get-pictures-on-your-posts/